# Koin - Ensure that all "by inject" are valid

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin

I work on an Android project using multiple Project Flavors, and we use Koin to inject the appropriate dependencies based on the current flavor.
We already use the `checkModules` Gradle task (described here : https://start.insert-koin.io/#/getting-started/testing?id=checking-your-modules) in order to ensure that our dependency tree is valid.

However, it seems that there is a use case missing.

Let's say I want to inject an `InterfaceA` in my Activity. I would write the following code :

```
class MyActivity : Activity() {

    private val interfaceA_Impl: InterfaceA by inject()
    ...
}
```

Koin requires the implementation of `InterfaceA` to be provided in a `module`, as such :

```
val myModule = module {
    single<InterfaceA> { MyInterfaceImpl() }
}
```

In my project, each implementation is "flavor-specific".

My question is :

Is there a way to ensure that **ALL** `by inject` targets are valid ? In other words, to ensure that all interfaces that I am trying to inject have valid implementations ? Currently, if an implementation is forgotten, the app crashes during runtime, and I would like to know about it sooner (maybe during unit tests, at the same time `checkModules` is ran ?)

Thanks a lot !